# How to give proper relative link in ajax ?

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller

I have developed MVC application.

I have published it on IIS ,There are few ajax methods in my app which dont work properly.

like,

```
http://demo.mycompanyname.in/Product/getProductDetails/?Id=1638
```

now, above method didnt work.

I have used below method in view to call above method.

```
 function getProductDetails(productCode, Index) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Product/getProductDetails/",
            data: { Id: productCode },

            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
            }
```

if I changed URL manually by putting 'myapp' my application name , 
(by typing in address bar)  it works...

```
http://demo.mycompanyname.in/myapp/Product/getProductDetails/?Id=1638
```

what change I have to make in ajax calling method ?

I have also tried this...

```
 url: "~/Product/getProductDetails/",
```

this is also wont work...

Comment: `above method didnt work.` do you see an error in console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are in razor view try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("getProductDetails","Product")'
    ...
```

---

if you are in an external js file. Define root url in your `_Layout.cshtml` like following:

```
<script>
    var app_root = '@Url.Content("~/")'
</script>
```

and use it in your ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: app_root + "/Product/getProductDetails/",    
    ...
```

---

Or again in your _Layout.cshtml you can write an url.resolve method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        Url =
        function () { }
        Url.prototype = {
            _relativeRoot: '@Url.Content("~/")',
                // create an extension method called "resolve"
                resolve: function (relative) {
                    var resolved = relative;
                    if (relative.charAt(0) == '~')
                        resolved = this._relativeRoot + relative;
                    return resolved;
                }
            }
    $Url = new Url();
</script>
```

and ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $Url.resolve("Product/getProductDetails"),    
    ...
```

After all, your project scripts will work independent from the sub-folders.